# IE hover compatibility issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am having an issue with IE compatibility for a project I am working on. The blue hover text shows up on FF and Chrome, but IE doesn't have an effect.

Here is the site: http://fortiswebsystems.com/showmetheparts/demo.html

Any ideas why IE doesn't render the blue background hover?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the proper header if you want IE9 to use current norm :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```